# polkadot-0.9.24 , cargo b -r , Error : unexpected character found: `\u{2}` at line 3779 column 58

Tags: polkadot-local

error: error parsing manifest: unexpected character found: `\u{2}` at line 3779 column 58

```
[lzh@c9 polkadot]$ git clone --depth 1 --branch release-v0.9.24 https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot.git  

[lzh@c9 polkadot]$ cd polkadot

[lzh@c9 polkadot]$ cargo b -r
error: error parsing manifest: unexpected character found: `\u{2}` at line 3779 column 58
```

Comment: -r works as shorthand for --release? nice... did not know that.

Comment: `git status` most likely something locally is corrupt or changed.

Answer (score 2):

With any errors related to compiling released versions of Substrate / Polkadot, I suggest you update your Rust compiler:

```sh
rustup update
```

I ran the same commands as you locally, and it worked just fine.

```sh
rustc --version
rustc 1.62.0-nightly (cb1219871 2022-05-08)
```